# How detect infinite loop in Java?

Tags: java, infinite-loop

I run a Java program, and it doesn't ends in a long time. I guess it may be a infinite loop in the code, but I can't see the code(can't modify it).

How to judge it's in a infinite loop or not?

---

It's an interview question and my answer is judge PC(program counter) is in loop or not. But the interviewer give me the hint `use stack and heap of that program`...

Comment: Use debug tool if you are using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans.

Comment: Use a java profile and check stats

Comment: Tell him that if you knew the answer then you would [be one step forward to become famous](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP).

Comment: Attach with the debugger, break all threads, and see what they are doing.

Comment: If you find out the answer for that question, there are thousands of Computer Scientists who would love to have a word with you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, you can't. That's the halting problem.

In practice, you can check for cycles in the call stack. Java should crash once it runs out of memory and dump a stack trace. Tedious, maybe potentially useful.

Comment: Re: "That's the halting problem": It's sort of the opposite of the halting problem; the halting problem only gives you the program source (and the input), whereas this problem lets you observe the running program but does *not* give you its source. (But even so, I agree, this is not going to be possible in all cases.)

Comment: The Java byte code is mathematically equivalent to the instructions of a Turing machine (except a Turing machine has infinite memory). So the "source" is there. But you won't find any "cycles in the call stack" when you're in an infinite loop. If it's heavily recursive, yes, but in a loop there is not necessarily anything happening on the call stack.

Comment: But the halting problem doesn't say that you can never tell whether a program halts or not (whether it is not in an infinite loop, to paraphrase loosely, or whether it is). The halting problem just says that you can't write a program that is *always* capable of telling. So in theory, you certainly can tell, in many cases, just not in all cases.